# How to get the public channel URL from YouTubeVideoFeed object using the YouTube API?

Tags: python, youtube, feed, youtube-api

I'm using the Python version of the YouTube API to get a YouTubeVideoFeed object using the following URL:

> http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/USERNAME/uploads

*Note: I've replaced USERNAME with the account I need to follow.*

So far getting the feed, iterating the entries, getting player urls, titles and thumbnails has all been straightforward.  But now I want to add a "Visit Channel" link to the page.  I can't figure out how to get the "public" URL of a channel (in this case, the default channel from the user) out of the feed.  From what I can tell, the only URLs stored directly in the feed point to the `http://gdata.youtube.com/`, *not* the public site.

How can I link to a channel based on a feed?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the youtube.com/user/USERNAME is a pretty safe bet if you want to construct the URL yourself, but I think what you want is the link rel='alternate'

You have to get the link array from the feed and iterate to find alternate, then grab the href

something like:

```
client = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()

feed = client.GetYouTubeVideoFeed('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username/uploads')

for link in feed.link:
  if link.rel == 'alternate':
    print link.href
```

Output:

http://www.youtube.com/profile_videos?user=username

The most correct thing would be to grab the 'alternate' link from the user profile feed, as technically the above URL goes to the uploaded videos, not the main channel page

```
feed = client.GetYouTubeUserEntry('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/username')

for link in feed.link:
  if link.rel == 'alternate':
    print link.href
```

output:
http://www.youtube.com/profile?user=username

Answer (score 0):

you might be confusing usernames... when I use my username I get my public page
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/drdredel/uploads
They have some wacky distinction between your gmail username and your youtube username. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: When I click your link it considers it an atom feed, I just want the public youtube channel page that people would normally visit.

Comment: is that accessed via api?  why not just go there directly like so: http://www.youtube.com/user/drdredel  ? again, maybe I'm not understanding you.

Comment: Perhaps I need to adjust what settings my script expects.  Right now it takes the gdata.youtube.com url, but perhaps I should just be passing a channel name or username.