# How to get all the videos thumbnails and information shown in Youtube channel?

Tags: objective-c, youtube, youtube-api, google-data-api, youtube-channels

I have a simple application which has to show the thumbnails of videos present at a particular channel and the links associated with them in a tableview, I have integrated google data api in my application also but I am unable to proceed further, I have also seen same type of question at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776110/how-to-get-the-public-channel-url-from-youtubevideofeed-object-using-the-youtube)

But I am not able to get the code working, can anybody suggest me how to start. I don't need any type of authentication because I am showing a public channel only

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse this url:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/**username**

You will get a xml respose from this url. Parse and use it as you want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer buddy I did it ages ago, using the same thing. +1 for your answer, but one thing I want to tell you is you really don't need to parse XML. You should google-data-api that automatically parse the things and returns the feeds to you.