# Retrieve feed from a specific category with appengine python youtube api

Tags: python, google-app-engine, youtube-api

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/articles/youtube_api_appengine.html Following this tutorial I am able to retrive the most recent video feeds for my service.

```
feed = client.GetRecentlyFeaturedVideoFeed()
```

with the above command, I would like to retrieve videos for the four standar youtube categories news, comedy, sports, music so I guess I should query it somehow like:

```
feed = client.Query('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/Comedy?v=2')
```

I am not able to figure out the syntax or even if I going the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was quite simple in a similar post

```
feed = client.GetYouTubeVideoFeed('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/-/Comedy?v=2')
```

and the relevant post: [How to get the public channel URL from YouTubeVideoFeed object using the YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776110/how-to-get-the-public-channel-url-from-youtubevideofeed-object-using-the-youtube)